# Laravel 5 hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables: `company` <-> `users` <-> `invoice`.

A company `hasMany` users.

A user `belongsTo` a company and, and a user `hasMany` invoices.

An invoice `belongsTo` a user.

Now I have an invoice with information about user (customer), and I want to get the user its information about the company so I made an:

An invoice `hasManyThrough` users, company (so gets the company through user)

Now it doesn't work as it is needed.

**Models:**

```
class Company extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'companies';

    public function users() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id');
    }

    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Company', 'App\User');
    }
}

class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function usertype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UserType','usertype_id','id');
    }

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','company_id','id');
    }

    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
    }

}

class Invoice extends Model {

    protected $table = 'invoices';

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Invoice Controller:**

```
class InvoiceController extends Controller {

    private $invoice;

    public function __construct(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
    }

    public function index(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $invoices = $invoice->with('users', 'company')->get();

        dd($invoices);

        return view('invoice.index', compact('invoices'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store()
    {

    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::with('users')->find($id);

        return view('invoice.show', compact('invoice'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The dd($invoices) will give a `BadMethodCallException 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::company()`

Any further needed information can be provided!

Answer (score 7):

Let's say we have table A and B and C
where table A has many of B (OneToMany) and B has many of C (OneToMany)
inorder to access the table C from table A you can use the Laravel shortcut (HasManyThrough) on the Table A and the problem is solved

**BUT** If you have table A and B and C
where table A has many of B (OneToMany) and B has many of C (ManyToMany)
you cannot use the laravel's (HasManyThrough) shortcut to access the table C from table A, {because of the pivot table in the middle between B and C} what you can do in this case is very simple:

In this example table A will be [courses], table B will be [chapters], and table C will be [videos]
where every course has may chapters, while a chapter can belong to only one course. in the other hand every chapter has many videos while a video can belong to many chapters.

```
<?php namespace Moubarmij\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Video extends Eloquent{

   protected $table = 'videos';

    /*************************************************************
     * Query Scopes
     **************************************************************/

    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('published', '=', '1');
    }

    public function scopeOrdered($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('order_number', 'ASC');
    }

    /*************************************************************
     * Relations
     **************************************************************/

    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Moubarmij\Models\Chapter', 'chapters_videos');
    }


}
```

---

```
<?php namespace Moubarmij\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Chapter extends Eloquent{

   protected $table = 'chapters';

    /*************************************************************
     * Query Scopes
     **************************************************************/

    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        return $query->where('published', '=', '1');
    }

    public function scopeOrdered($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('order_number', 'ASC');
    }

    public function scopeWithVideos($query)
    {
        return $query->with(['videos' => function($q)
        {
            $q->ordered();
        }]);
    }


    /*************************************************************
     * Relations
     **************************************************************/

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Moubarmij\Models\Video', 'chapters_videos');
    }

}
```

---

```
<?php namespace Moubarmij\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Course extends Eloquent{

   protected $table = 'courses';

    /*************************************************************
     * Query Scopes
     **************************************************************/

    public function scopeVisible($query)
    {
        return $query->where('visible', '=', '1');
    }

    public function scopeOrdered($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('order_number', 'ASC');
    }

    public function scopeWithChapters($query)
    {
        return $query->with(['chapters' => function($q)
        {
            $q->ordered();
        }]);
    }

    public function scopeWithChaptersAndVideos($query)
    {
        return $query->with(['chapters' => function($q)
        {
            $q->ordered()->withVideos();
        }]);
    }


    /*************************************************************
     * Relations
     **************************************************************/

    public function chapters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Moubarmij\Models\Chapter');
    }


}
```

Comment: Do I have to use the query scopes as well or just the relations?

Comment: @Synyster you don't have to use the scopes but they are very recommended, since without them you will be repeating this peace of code everyplace you use it. However the most important scope in this example if the `scopeWithChaptersAndVideos ` if you want to have its results without using the scope will have to write its content and replace the `withVideos ` with the content of that scope as well from the videos model.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in the Course class, so when you use ->with('chapters'), it automatically loads the videos too:

```
public function chapters()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Moubarmij\Models\Chapter')->with('videos');
}
```

Comment: Years later, this is my go-to solution. Way simpler!