# How to do nested eloquent relation

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 model. Example they are A, B, and C. A is hasMany B, and C hasOne B. Example the relation between A & B is "relationB". so if I retrieve the data from A, I can do "A::with('relationB')". 
My problem is, how can I access the relation between B & C if I retrieve all datas from A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 hasManyThrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529224/laravel-5-hasmanythrough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it by the following line:

```
A::with('B.C')->get()
```

Then every A-object will have their associated B models, and every B-model will have their C-objects included.